# How to auto-activate the environment after the start in version 1.56?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there any way how to auto-activate the environment in VS Code 1.56?

Previously, I used the following workspace settings to auto-activate the environment in the terminal:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [
    "/path/to/activate.sh",
],
```

It activated the environment right after starting up.

These settings were deprecated in the latest version:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_terminal

I tried to use the new settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "bash": {
        "path": "bash",
        "args": [
            "/path/to/activate.sh",
        ],
    },
},
```

Unfortunately, it only works for New Terminals or when I have a different tab open after the start and switch to Terminal after VS Code is fully loaded.

Is there any way how to activate the environment rightaway?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in my `settings.json`:

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": ["-l"]
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
```

Make sure to add the "args" key to the shell you are using. In my case it is zsh so I added the "-l" argument to load my .zprofile script.

Hopes this helps you out! :)

For more details on Terminal Profiles Confs checkout: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55#_terminal-profiles

Comment: Does it work for you in VS Code 1.56?

By working I mean whether it's activated on startup. The syntax works for me when I open a new Terminal, but if the Terminal is open at startup it won't activate the environment.

`Make sure to add the "args" key to the shell you are using.` |


I use this key as shown in the example I provided.

Comment: Yes it works on start up. But if you want to activate a venv you need to add: `"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,` and for python add: `"python.venvPath": "./<venv_name>"` to the setting file. NOTE also make sure you have selected the right interperter

Comment: My current VS Code version is 1.56.2

Comment: I tried adding "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal", but it hasn't changed anything. I already had "python.venvPath" specified, although there is a warning "This setting can only be applied in user settings in local window or in remote settings in remote window.".

Do you have the environment configured in the user settings or the workspace settings?

Comment: I am using the user settings, but workspace setting should trump the user setting if set. So make sure to be consistent on both setting. I have a defined structure that I always follow on my projects, that is why I use the user settings.

Comment: I use Poetry and I have a different environment for each project so I can't configure the environment in the user settings. That could be the reason why the activation works in your case. It's unfortunately not applicable for my use case since I need to configure it in the workspace settings. The main point is it worked fine for a long time until VS Code 1.56.

Answer (score 0):

To "auto" activate a python venv and load .env file on the integrated terminal when you open the project or open another terminal make sure you have the following settings set:

#### User Setting UI

```
Python: Env File
${workspaceFolder}/.env
Python>Terminal: Activate Env In Current Terminal
True
Python>Terminal: Activate Environment
True
```

Make sure you venv is at the root of you project folder, eg:

```
./MyProject (workspaceFolder)
./MyProject/venv
./MyProject/.env
./MyProject/djangoproject
./MyProject/djangoproject/[djangoapps]
./MyProject/djangoproject/manage.py
./MyProject/setup.py
./MyProject/requirements.txt
```

If that fails try setting the workspace settings to:

```
"python.pythonPath": "./venv/bin/python",
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
```

As a reference here are my current setting:

#### User settings.json:

```
{
    "python.sortImports.path": "./venv/bin/python",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": ["-l"]
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": ["-l"]
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
}
```

#### Workspace setting.json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "./venv/bin/python",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
}
```